# PHP: Access parent key within nested foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, nested

EDIT*************

There was no issue with my loop, turns out I just had one of those tricky "Quotation mark' errors. I'd like to blame it on Monday morning but well, that was just dumb haha. Well I guess here's an example of what works lol:

What I'm doing is this:

```
$array = [
  0 => [
    0 => 1,
    1 => 3
  ],
  1 => [
    0 => 5,
    1 => 4
  ]
]

foreach($array as $key=>$value){
  foreach($value as $_key=>$_value){
    echo "Parent key: " . $key . " Child value: " . $_value; 
  }
}
```

This works great. *palm in face*

Comment: [Works for me](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AnEr3K). Just fix your obvious syntax errors like the misisng `$` before your variable names.

Answer (score 2):

you have a typo error in first foreach loop

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
```

it should be `$array` and not `array`

Comment: lol, yes there was a typo there, my bad, edited. That's not the issue however, in my actual case I have the correct syntax. The issue is that within the nested foreach, it trips up when trying to echo the parent $key.

Comment: it works for me like the result is 
`Parent key: 0 Child value: 1
Parent key: 0 Child value: 3
Parent key: 1 Child value: 5
Parent key: 1 Child value: 4`
what result do you expect ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you forgot a $ before array.

Answer (score 0):

Replace (You forgot a $ before array.)

```
foreach(array as $key=>$value){
 foreach($value as $_key=>$_value){
 echo "Parent key: " . $key . " Child value: " . $_value; 
  }
 }
```

With

```
  foreach($array as $key=>$value){
   foreach($value as $_key=>$_value){
    echo "Parent key: " . $key . " Child value: " . $_value; 
}
}
```